# Live streaming from webcam to website, no flash

Tags: html, video, webcam, live-streaming

sorry in advance for my english...I'm going straight to the point: I'm developing a website and in one page I have to include a video player/html5 video/whatever that shows a streaming webcam (actually, my PC webcam), and that video has to be seen also from mobile. I don't wanna use UStream or similar, just a custom and personal live streaming.

So, these are the entities and the stream:
PC Windows with webcam -> Server with website (and its own IP) -> Clients (other people) with pc/mobile (so no flash or plugins) that can view what my webcam streams.

Until now, I tried above all VLC, but with no results  (maybe I was doing something wrong).

Waiting for your solutions (maybe a step-by-step one)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebRTC RTCPeerConnection. Check the WebRTC [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) and the RTCPeerConnection [demo](http://www.simpl.info/rtcpeerconnection/).

Comment: Yeah, that's nice, but I need (unfortunately) something that works also on (bleah!) IE, and WebRTC does not.